# Expected primary-expression before numeric constant

Tags: c++

For the below code

```
#include<iostream>

template<bool T>
class Invert
{
public:
    static bool const result = !T;
};

int main()
{
    bool test = Invert<1-1>::result;
    std::cout << "test " <<test << "\n";
    bool test1 = Invert<1 + 1>::result;
    std::cout << "test1 " << test1 << "\n";
    bool test2 = Invert<1 || 1>::result;
    std::cout << "test2 " << test2 << "\n";
    bool test3 = Invert<0 && 1>::result;
    std::cout << "test3 " << test3 << "\n";
    bool test4 = Invert<1 < 1>::result;
    std::cout << "test4 " << test4 << "\n";
    bool test5 = Invert<1 > 1>::result;//error error: expected primary-expression before numeric constant
    std::cout << "test5 " << test5 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Getting error at line no 22

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()': main.cpp:22:26: error: expected
>   primary-expression before numeric constant   bool test5 = Invert<1 >
>   1>::result;

if I comment those lines it works perfectly 
[Working example with commented error line](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=faf7ba5c1cdaf412)

**Added question after solution comments**

Since I understood from the comments that it was because of parsing 
but why didn't I got problem in  `bool test4 = Invert<1 < 1>::result;` How come parser was smart this time

Comment: Well, what is `Invert<1 >`?

Comment: it thinks the first > is closing the template parameter list, wrap that in parentheses

Comment: Just replace `<1 > 1>` with `<(1 > 1)>`.

Comment: Parentheses are your friend: `Invert<1 > 1>` -> `Invert<(1 > 1)>`

Comment: off topic question .Anyone knows how to change the question title as it is not reflecting the exact problem .As it is more related to template parsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow correct parsing, you have to use parenthesis:

```
bool test5 = Invert<(1 > 1)>::result;
```

Comment: there was no problem with  bool test4 = Invert<1 < 1>::result; how did the parsing determined in this case  < is for comparing

Comment: @HariomSingh - Because the opening bracket for the template was already  seen. It's not like it was expecting another one, innit?

Comment: The parser scans things from the left to the right. If it sees `Invert<1>`, it thinks it’s seen a complete template, but if it sees `Invert<1<` it can’t possibly interpret it as a complete template.